# Allow certain users to access a specific directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, symbolic-link

I'm trying to figure out how to allow certain users who are also me to access a directory of files that I want to use for all of my users.

The files I want to use are on `account1` in the directory `/home/account1/public_html/source/engines` and I want the directory `/home/account2/public_html/source/engines` to use the same exact files without having to upload them to both places every time I change them, so I created a simple symbolic link and added `account2` to the group `account1` (while still keeping its own group as the primary). It still gives me a **Permission Denied** error though. Is there any way I can grant `account2` and other accounts that I create for myself access to those files? I don't want them to be global to all users because I don't want my hosted users to be able to access them, only my users.

`groups account1` returns `account1 : account1`

`groups account2` returns `account2 : account2 account1`

`/home/account1/public_html/source/engines` and all its files belongs to `account1:account1`

Any other information you might need just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you have the right permissions for the groups (chmod g+rw for files and chmod g+rwx for directories)
- Also if you are testing permissions from the shell, sometimes new groups apply after you logout and in again

If those fail, it could point to other permission controls (on top of standard linux ones), such as SELinux. If you have control over it, try disabling to verify that's not causing a problem.